# AlertDialog.Builder com espaço indevido

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com um espaço no bottom do meu AlertDialog customizado. Não sei o porque está acontecendo, sabendo que eu não setei nenhum margin ou padding no fim da minha view. Se alguém puder ajudar.

Aqui está um print real do que está acontecendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o meu código usado...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="#5454C3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#FF33CC">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="DESTINO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroRegiao">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnEstadoFretes"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#00FF00">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="COMPLEMENTO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroComplemento">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnComplemento"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="PREÇO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/editTextFiltroPreco">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnPreco"
                android:layout_marginTop="-14dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="#000000">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <br.lgfelicio.elementos.TextViewChanged
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progresTexto"
                android:textColor="#9B9B9B"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="RAIO" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/raioSeekBar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Resolvido!**

O problema é que eu estava usando layout_marginTop negativo, e de alguma forma, o layout não recalculava a altura, porque o elemento subia, mas pro layout ele continua ali na mesma posição.

Estava assim...

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#C0C1C0"
    android:layout_marginTop="-19dp"/>
```

Quando removi o -19, o espaço que tinha no bottom sumiu. E então quando coloquei a View dentro de um LinearLayout, eu consegui colocar margin negativo sem ter o problema de espaço no final.

Agora ficou assim...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C0C1C0"
        android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda! Valeu.

Comment: Este é todo o codigo que voce esta usando?

Comment: Sim, é todo o código usado...

Comment: tente alterar essa propiedade aqui: android:paddingBottom="5dp", altere para 0dp...

Comment: O padding que você falou pra tirar, é do primeiro grupo de elemento que foi criado, no caso não iria interferir no último elemento do Alerta...

Answer (score 1):

Remova esta linha do Linear Layout

```
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
```

linha 157

Comment: Não funcionou... No caso se eu remover essa linha, ele vai colar do lado esquerdo, e eu quero é remover o espaço no final que está ficando ali sem eu ter colocado... Porque se deixar, os botões ficam longe demais do último elemento.

Comment: Eu olhei a imagem e o que achei que você queria mudar era o espaço no lado esquerdo no LinearLayout